# Error when implement a forgot password ANDROID

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Im trying to implement a forgot password function into my application using a php file but i met with some error. I ask user for their email aftermath i store them in params so that my php file can grab the email and sent it to them.

Below is my code:

```
btnPasswordSubmit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // new ForgotPassword().execute();
            String recoveryPassword = txtRecoveryPassword.getText()
                    .toString();

            // Building Parameters
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", recoveryPassword));
            // getting JSON Object
            // Note that create event URL accepts POST method
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    forgotPassword_url, "POST", params);

            // check log cat for response
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

            // check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully email sent
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                            ForgotPasswordSuccessActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to create event
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
```

Here is my logcat:

```
08-22 16:32:58.904: E/JSON Parser(271): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
08-22 16:32:58.924: E/AndroidRuntime(271): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-22 16:32:58.924: E/AndroidRuntime(271): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-22 16:32:58.924: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at com.stts.sparetimetradingsystem.ForgotPasswordActivity$1.onClick(ForgotPasswordActivity.java:57)
08-22 16:32:58.924: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
08-22 16:32:58.924: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
08-22 16:32:58.924: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-22 16:32:58.924: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-22 16:32:58.924: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-22 16:32:58.924: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-22 16:32:58.924: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-22 16:32:58.924: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-22 16:32:58.924: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-22 16:32:58.924: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-22 16:32:58.924: E/AndroidRuntime(271):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-22 16:39:22.534: E/JSON Parser(350): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
08-22 16:39:22.564: E/AndroidRuntime(350): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-22 16:39:22.564: E/AndroidRuntime(350): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-22 16:39:22.564: E/AndroidRuntime(350):  at com.stts.sparetimetradingsystem.ForgotPasswordActivity$1.onClick(ForgotPasswordActivity.java:57)
08-22 16:39:22.564: E/AndroidRuntime(350):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
08-22 16:39:22.564: E/AndroidRuntime(350):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8816)
08-22 16:39:22.564: E/AndroidRuntime(350):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-22 16:39:22.564: E/AndroidRuntime(350):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-22 16:39:22.564: E/AndroidRuntime(350):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-22 16:39:22.564: E/AndroidRuntime(350):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-22 16:39:22.564: E/AndroidRuntime(350):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-22 16:39:22.564: E/AndroidRuntime(350):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-22 16:39:22.564: E/AndroidRuntime(350):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-22 16:39:22.564: E/AndroidRuntime(350):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-22 16:39:22.564: E/AndroidRuntime(350):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-22 16:43:45.264: E/JSON Parser(378): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
08-22 16:43:45.294: E/AndroidRuntime(378): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-22 16:43:45.294: E/AndroidRuntime(378): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-22 16:43:45.294: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at com.stts.sparetimetradingsystem.ForgotPasswordActivity$ForgotPassword$1.run(ForgotPasswordActivity.java:85)
08-22 16:43:45.294: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-22 16:43:45.294: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-22 16:43:45.294: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:123)
08-22 16:43:45.294: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-22 16:43:45.294: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-22 16:43:45.294: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-22 16:43:45.294: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-22 16:43:45.294: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-22 16:43:45.294: E/AndroidRuntime(378):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-22 16:46:22.954: E/JSON Parser(409): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of 
08-22 16:46:22.976: E/AndroidRuntime(409): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-22 16:46:22.976: E/AndroidRuntime(409): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-22 16:46:22.976: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at com.stts.sparetimetradingsystem.ForgotPasswordActivity$1.onClick(ForgotPasswordActivity.java:62)

08-22 16:46:22.976: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
08-22 16:46:22.976: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.view.View.onKeyUp(View.java:4121)
08-22 16:46:22.976: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.widget.TextView.onKeyUp(TextView.java:4431)
08-22 16:46:22.976: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:1061)
08-22 16:46:22.976: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:3740)
08-22 16:46:22.976: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:788)
08-22 16:46:22.976: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:788)
08-22 16:46:22.976: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:788)
08-22 16:46:22.976: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:788)
08-22 16:46:22.976: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1667)
08-22 16:46:22.976: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1102)
08-22 16:46:22.976: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2063)
08-22 16:46:22.976: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1643)
08-22 16:46:22.976: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.view.ViewRoot.deliverKeyEventToViewHierarchy(ViewRoot.java:2471)
08-22 16:46:22.976: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleFinishedEvent(ViewRoot.java:2441)
08-22 16:46:22.976: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1735)
08-22 16:46:22.976: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-22 16:46:22.976: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-22 16:46:22.976: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-22 16:46:22.976: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-22 16:46:22.976: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-22 16:46:22.976: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-22 16:46:22.976: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-22 16:46:22.976: E/AndroidRuntime(409):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: What is on ForgotPasswordActivity.java:57?

Comment: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100306173450AAslzYx

Comment: @jones-ch What Astor means is, try running in Debug mode (not run mode), and the debugger will pause on the line that's causing the problem, and let you inspect all the values of your variables to see what's causing the problem.

Comment: @RaghavSood line 57 is // Note that create event URL accepts POST method.

Comment: Either jsonParse, forgotPassword_url or params is null. Use debugging to find out which one.

Answer (score 0):

Are you testing this with an empty String? Based on this line from the logcat:

```
08-22 16:32:58.904: E/JSON Parser(271): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
```

it looks like it's trying to parse an empty string and failing.